# Does Spiritual Weapon benefit from Divine Strike?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cleric

Several Cleric domains have the Divine Strike feature giving bonuses to weapon attacks. Does Spiritual Weapon benefit from this feature?

Answer (score 22):

## No

Divine Strike (PHB, pp60) requires

> ...when you hit a creature with a **weapon attack**

and Spiritual Weapon states (PHB, pp278)

> ...make a **melee spell attack**

Because you are using a spell attack rather than a weapon attack, Divine Strike can't be used with Spiritual weapon.

Comment: I can see where the confusion could arise; the title doesn't match the description of the effect.

Comment: @Chemus yeah, there is this kind of confusion everywhere. See Mr. Crawford clarify the Leomund tiny hut spell: https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/823774362293542912 (Mr. Crawford, read your own book - lolz)